# How Do I change css with nodejs?

Tags: html, css, node.js

I have this "Log in" page.

I wanted to make it so that, if the user clicks "Log In" and all the input fields aren't filled or error or something that it would change the input border color red and shadow.

I'm using nodejs express ig. and its in a form I'm using method post. I tried getting stuff with "document.." but that doesn't work. any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript **running in the browser** can manipulate the DOM via the API provided through the [`document` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document).

On the server there is no document. The browser makes an HTTP request. The server generates an HTTP response. When the response is HTML it is usually generated from either a static file or a template.

If you want to dynamically modify the document, a template is the best way to do this.

You could do something along the lines of:

```
<input name="something" class="<%= fields_with_errors.includes('something') ? 'errors' : '' %>" value="<%= user_input.something %>">
```

Where `fields_with_errors` is an array and `user_input` is an object holding the values the user entered when they submitted the form.

The specifics depend on the template language you pick.

There are [numerous template languages](https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-nodejs-html-templating-engine-libraries) you can use with Node.js. Pick one and integrate it with the code you use to process and response to HTTP requests. Many people use [Express](https://expressjs.com/) to do this. MDN has [a tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Tutorial_local_library_website). There are lots of middlewares to add [template support to Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) and the MDN tutorial covers [them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/skeleton_website#what_view_engine_should_i_use).